# JacksonMapping Polymorphic

Tags: jackson2

I am trying to parse json structure https://developers.nest.com/documentation/api-reference

Where device could be various types i want jackson to instantiate relevant objects Thermostat/SmokeAlarm,Camera etc

```
@Data
@ToString
public class Nest {
    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    private Metadata metadata;

    @JsonProperty("structures")
    private HashMap<String, Structure> structures;

    @JsonProperty("devices")
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Device>> devices;
}
```

How would i use@JsonTypeinfo to decided which type to instatntite based on values in keys.

Another question would be how woul i get rid of all these multilevel nestings and cal have something like

```
@JsonProperty("devices")
private List<Device> devices;
```

parsed according to keys/subtypes

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: Not yet, I am using a hack for now